# node 14 causing unknown issues for graphqljs

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js

So I recently tried upgrading my node from 13 to 14, but afterwards I was having issues with graphql.

What happened was that I was forever "pending" whenever I sent a request to the server. The problem is, there's no errors being thrown.

I'm wondering if anyone has had any issues with graphql when upgrading from 13 to 14.

Packages used:

- express-graphql
- graphql
- graphql-iso-date
- graphql-query-builder-v2
- graphql-type-json
- graphql-upload

If you don't have any problems with node 14 and these two graphql packages, please let me know, as it's then other packages that are causing the issue. Thanks.

My current solution is to downgrade node (I'm currently on node 12 since brew doesn't seem to have node 13 yet).

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @madflow postgresql, I am using pg-promise to connect to it

Comment: Since you are using `pg-promise`, set the dependency to `"pg-promise">=10.5.2`, remove `node_modules` and do fresh install of dependencies. That should fix it for you once and for all. Also see my comment to the answer by `madflow`.

Comment: @vitaly-t it was definitely caused by `pg`. I'm pretty sure it's a dependency, so it's being used somewhere. Updating it fixed the perpetual pending.

Comment: @vitaly-t i realize that I was also using `connect-simple-pg`, so I think that was the main culprit.

Comment: @A.Lau If `pg` is used somewhere else in your project, directly, outside `pg-promise`, then yes, sure, you would have to set `pg>=8.0.3`, but if you only use `pg-promise` as a dependency in your project, then setting it to the right version and reinstalling will suffice.

Comment: About `connect-simple-pg`, yes, that would cause the problem, and you indeed would have to force the version of `pg` by setting it explicitly.

Comment: @vitaly-t it was a mess of a code. I switched to using jwt instead, since I needed to use pg to create a pool. Great library btw.

Comment: I have just opened [a new issue there](https://github.com/voxpelli/node-connect-pg-simple/issues/172).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known [issue](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2180) in the `pg` module and NodeJS 14. Since `pg-promise` also uses this module - I suspect this is the problem.

The proposed solution is to make sure you have `pg>=8.0.3` installed.

This can be done by

- updating to `pg-promise>=10.5.2` which already has the updated `pg` module as a dependency and/or
- updating to `pg>=8.0.3` in the dependencies if explicitly specified.

Also make sure that any other library depending on `pg` is up to date.

Comment: i will try it tomorrow, seems like a logical connection, thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. The author stated that he is using `pg-promise`, which since `v10.5.2` had `pg` driver version fixed at `8.0.3`. This means the right solution is to have `"pg-promise">=10.5.2`, and not `pg>=8.0.3`.

Comment: @vitaly-t The culprit is the `pg` module. Some people explicitly pin `pg` as dependency. So I disagree that this is not "right". I will however update the answer with the additional info :)

Comment: @madflow See comments within the question. The culprit is `pg-connect-simple`, for which [I have opened a new issue](https://github.com/voxpelli/node-connect-pg-simple/issues/172). Other than that, if one does not include other modules with their own `pg` dependencies, then updating `pg-promise` dependency as specified is the right way. So in your answer the best thing is to explain it that way.