# Postgres server is not responding to a nodejs request

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have access to a remote postgres DB from pgAdmin4 and I also could access from nodejs using a Mac. Right now I'm using the same code to access the DB in Windows. The code for my connection is the following:

```
const { Client } = require('pg'); //Importing the Postgres package
const hosts= require('../hosts'); //Using the file containig all hosts 
const connectionData = { //Begin creating the connection settings object
   host: hosts.DBHost, //DB host   
   port: hosts.DBPort, //DB hosts port
   database: hosts.DB, //DB
   user: hosts.DBUser, //DB user
   password: hosts.DBPassword, //DB user password
 }
```

My test is the following:

```
var client = new Client(connectionData); //New client instance using the above connection settings
client.connect(); //Open the connection to the database()  
sql = "select * from myTable";
client.query(sql) 
  .then(response => {
    console.log ({"data": response}); //This isn't shown 
  })
  .catch(err => { 
    console.log({"error": err}); //This isn't shown neither 
  })
```

No error, no exception, the DB server doesn't respond!

Why isn't the server responding?

Comment: Are you using Node.JS 14?

Comment: Also: Post your `package.json` - if any.

Comment: Nodejs v14.1.0
npm v6.14.4

Comment: `
{
  "name": "myServer",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "csprng": "^0.1.2",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3",
    "pg": "^8.0.2",
    "sha.js": "^2.4.11"
  }
}
`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect that you have the same problem like in this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61587910/node-14-causing-unknown-issues-for-graphqljs/61588121#61588121). Since it is not a 100% duplicate I will post this again:

There is a [known issue](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2180) in the pg module and NodeJS 14.

The proposed solution is to make sure you have `pg>=8.0.3` installed.

This can be done by updating `pg` in the dependencies.

Also make sure, that any other library depending on the `pg` module, is also up to date and has the latest `pg` version.

If this is not possible for any reason - using Node 12 should also work.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you! It took me too long to find this.