# Sequelize can't connect to postgres on docker

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js

When i try to run my server sequelize not connect to database and for consequence none of my model are created.

My docker-compose

```
version: "3.7"
services:
   backend:
    build: ./Trademon-Backend
    environment:
      DB_USER: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: postgres
      DB_NAME: Trademon
      DB_HOST: database
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_DIALECT: postgres
      DB_RECREATE: 1 # To recreate database
      JWT_SECRET: TrademonSecret
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./Trademon-Backend:/backend/
      - /backend/node_modules/
    depends_on:
      - database
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "database:5432", "--", "nodemon"]

  database:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: Trademon
    volumes:
      - ~/databases/Trademon:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
```

My app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const logger = require("morgan");
const passport = require("passport");

const db = require("./models/index").sequelize;

const usersRouter = require("./routes/v1/users");

const app = express();

const RECREATE_DB = !!+process.env.DB_RECREATE || false;

require("./config/passport");

/**
 * Passport initialization
 */
app.use(passport.initialize());

/**
 * Database connection
 */

console.log("Trying to connect to database...");

try {
  db.authenticate();
  console.log("Connection to database has been established successfully.");

  if (RECREATE_DB) {
    console.log("Recreating database!");
    db.sync({ force: true });
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", err);
}

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use("/v1/users", usersRouter);

app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send("Sorry this page does not exist!");
});

module.exports = app;
```

My sequelize config

```
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const config = require(__dirname + "/../config/database.js")[env];
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,
    config
  );
}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (
      file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js"
    );
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

[My log on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqiKc.png)

I dont get errors from db.authenticate() but nothing happened and the execution proceed to the next lines (console.logs).

Any help?

---

Edit: 
This is an incompatibility with node v14, so downgrade to v13 ou LTS solved my problem.

Comment: Please post the `Trademon-Backend` Dockerfile and your package.json

Comment: Thank you, but after search for issues on sequelize github i found that the problem is the node version, i have node:current on dockerfile and when i have changed it to lts or 13 it runs without problems.

[Github issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12158)

Comment: Upgrading to pg@8.0.3  should do the trick, [too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611039/postgres-server-is-not-responding-to-a-nodejs-request/61615233#61615233).

Answer (score 1):

Stop your application:

```
docker-compose down
```

Clean up your databases files:

```
rm -rf ~/databases/Trademon/*
```

Then start again:

```
docker-compose up
```

and then restore database backup if any.

Comment: Thank you, but after search for issues on sequelize github i found that the problem is the node version, i have node:current on dockerfile and when i have changed it to lts or 13 it runs without problems.

[Github issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12158)