# Why is node-postgres (pg) hanging when I call client.connect()?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, freeze, node-postgres

I recently had to upgrade my node.js version for my vue.js application (node.js on the backend) from v13.5.0 to v14.5.0. I reinstalled all my node packages, upgrading the ones I had to upgrade, and now the application hangs on all DB calls. We are using pg (node-postgres) for our database calls. I upgraded pg to version 7.18.2.

Our initialization code looks like this:

```
constructor() {
  this.pg = require('pg');
  this.client = null;
  this.initPromise = null;
}

async init() {
  if (!this.initPromise) {
    this.client = new this.pg.Client({
      application_name: 'Back end',
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      }
    });
    this.initPromise = this.client.connect();
  }
  return this.initPromise;
}

async query(query, params) {
  await this.init();
  return await this.client.query(query, params);
}
```

I put console logs around the call to this.init() as follows:

```
console.log('before');
await this.init();
console.log('after');
```

'after' never prints out.

Does anyone know why it hangs now that I've upgrade my node version?

Comment: The `init` method should not be `async` since you're not using `await` inside of it, but that's unrelated to the problem

Comment: Where are you passing the connection details and credentials to the client?

Comment: What version of node-postgres did you have installed previsously?

Comment: According to the node-postgres documents (https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting), it grabs the connection details from the environment variables. But I tried passing them to the Client constructor explicitly: this.client = new this.pg.Client({host: ..., database: ..., etc.}); but to no avail. I had 7.8.0 installed previously.

Answer (score 14):

It seems that pg v.8.3.0 solves this problem. I got v7.18.2 from running npm install pg. Seems that doesn't always install the latest version. npm install pg@latest does the trick.

Comment: Had the same problem, spent a good 2 hours trying to fix this. Can confirm updating to the the latest version fixed it.

Comment: The root cause is that node 14 introduced a change that broke pg. Upgrading pg solves it. I just spent ages trying to understand why simple postgres code wasn't working in dev but was fine in prod which uses node 12. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611039/postgres-server-is-not-responding-to-a-nodejs-request

Comment: I was about to lose my mind until I stumbled upon this. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

@gib65 upgrading to v.8.3.0 did the trick for me too was banging my head on await and async. thought i was being a n00b again...

Comment: Hi madmus, I suppose it is preferable to add a comment to reply to a comment. Your comment doesn't seems to be an answer to the question.